# Zend Bootstrap How do I autoload a model?

Tags: zend-framework, model, bootstrapping

I have an auth plugin working. I am trying to add ACL to it according to the excellent video series at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6qsSnLfcmE&feature=relmfu.

My problem is that when I try to register the model in Bootstrap so that I can pass the instance to the plugin, I get a server 500 error. My bootstrap looks like this...

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_AutoLoader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH));

    $acl = new Model_SystemAcl;
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fc->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl,$auth));

    return $modelLoader;
}

}
```

It is the line:

```
$acl = new Model_SystemAcl;
```

That is causing the problem. If I comment it out (and the $acl parameter that is passed) it works fine. It appears as though somehow my system is not configured properly to load models. This is the entire Bootstrap shown in the tutorial btw. Perhaps there is something in Application.ini I need?

EDIT: Yes, SystemAcl.php exists and is in [applicationdir]/models

Comment: SystemAcl.php not Model_SystemAcl.php

Comment: Yes, I mis-typed. the filename is SystemAcl.php and it is in the models directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a full example for load models from the application namespace "Application"

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
    array(
         'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
         'namespace' => 'Application',
    )
);
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('model', 'models/', 'Model');

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);
```

Comment: Turn out the problem was in the instancing in Bootstrap. It was an error in the model itself. Sorry for the false alarm guys and thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1):

Try to instantiate resources that may not yet have loaded i not a good practice.

You should use an Controller Plugin instead.

Comment: Actually, I am using a controller plugin. I need to pass the instances to the plugin because plugins do not have access to the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your setup the filename of your class should be `SystemAcl.php`, not `Model_SystemAcl.php`.

Comment: Yes, it is. That was a mis-typed bit on my part. I fixed it up above.

Answer (score 0):

if it is in application/models then i would have thought the script should be Models_SystemAcl not Model_SystemAcl (no 's'). Saying that, it is better to use plugins in the long run, rather than sticking this sort of stuff in the bootstrap. Those tutorials are good though :)

Comment: At it says, I am using a plugin. But it is a preDispatch plugin for authentication.

Comment: Right - and have you checked that it is Models_SystemAcl and not Model_SystemAcl? ie application/models vs application/model

Comment: That would be incorrect. The default directory is models and the classname is Model_ This is standard Zend. And it is this way in the tutorial video and his works. That's why I am perplexed.